# export environment varible from bash script with argument

Tags: bash, variables, arguments, environment

I am trying to export environment variable using a bash script which takes one argument. I tried to run the script using source command, but it does not work.

```
source ./script.sh dev
```

My example script below

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check 1 argument is passed with the script
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage : $0 AWS account: e.g. $0 dev"
        exit 0
fi

# convert the input to uppercase
aws_env=$( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$1" )


if ! [[ "$aws_env" =~ ^(DEV|UAT|TRN|PROD)$ ]]; then 
    # check that correct account is provided
    echo "Enter correct AWS account: dev or uat or trn or prod"
    exit 0

else
    # export environment variables
    file="/home/xyz/.aws/key_${aws_env}"
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < $file
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${lines[0]}
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${lines[1]}
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2
    echo "AWS access keys and secret has been exported as environment variables for $aws_env account"
fi
```

Content of file /home/xyz/.aws/key_DEV. Its a sample only, not real keys.

```
$ cat key_DEV 
123
xyz
```

When I say it does not work, nothing happens in the terminal, it closes the terminal when I run the script.

## Further update:

When I run the script as is from the terminal without source (`./script.sh dev`) it seems to be working fine, with the debug (`set -x`), I can see all the outputs are correct.

However, the issue is when I run with source (`source ./script.sh dev`), then it fails (closes the terminal, now I know why, because of exit 0), and from the output captured from the debug command I can see that its not capturing $1 argument correctly. The error message `"Enter correct AWS account: dev or uat or trn or prod"`. And, the value of `$aws_env` variable is blank.

I don't know why the two behaviors are different and how to fix it.

## Final update:

The script seems to be fine. The issue was local to my computer. `tr` was defined as an alias in `.bashrc` file which was causing the problem. I just used `typeset -u aws_env="$1"` instead of `aws_env=$( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$1" )`. Thank you all for helping me to get this one resolved, specifically @markp-fuso.

Comment: Please add content of `/home/xyz/.aws/key_DEV` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Replace `exit` with `return` since the script is intended to be sourced. Otherwise it may exit the current shell when it is sourced.

Comment: @Cyrus, I have updated the post with the content of /home/xyz/.aws/key_DEV

Comment: @Nejat I am trying the script with correct input, so its not matching the first condition of the if statement. So, thats not relevant right now.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: please update the question with more details besides *"it does not work"*; error message? no output? wrong output? the `AWS_*` variables are set but not exported? something else?

Comment: fwiw, the current script works for me: `source ./script.sh dev; typeset -p | grep AWS` => `declare -x AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="123"` / `declare -x AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="ap-southeast-2"` / `declare -x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xyz"`

Comment: You've only got two lines in the file; don't mess around with nonstandard features of `read` to populate the two variables. Just use `{ IFS= read -r AWS_ACCESS_KEY; IFS= read -r AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY; } < "$file"`.

Comment: @markp-fuso I have updated the post with what happens when I run the script

Comment: @chepner - when I use the single liner for file read,still the same result. terminal closes

Comment: You should be using a non-zero exit status to indicate an error.

Comment: what do you mean by *"not capturing $1 argument correctly"*? what is the value of `$1`?

Comment: as I commented before, the script works for me when I run `source ./script.sh dev`; I'm running `bash 4.4.12` at the command line; are you sure you're running `bash` at the command line? from your command prompt, what do you get when you run `echo $0` and `ps -p $$`?

Comment: @markp-fuso I am certainly using bash. See output. `echo $0` `bash`  and `bash --version` the output `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @markp-fuso - the value of `$1` argument should be `dev` , which I can see when i run the script without `source`. But when I run with `source`, the value of `$1` is null, its basically empty.

Comment: you've mentioned the 'failed' run generates the message `"Enter correct AWS account: dev or uat or trn or prod".`, which indicates something is in `$1` and `aws_env` (otherwise you should receive the `Usage:...` message, right?); after the failed run what does `typeset -p aws_env` return?

Comment: Finally got it resolved. Thanks to @markp-fuso for continuously trying to put me back on the right track over and again. Other posts which helped me @M. Nejat Aydin changing the exit to return, which stopped closing the terminal and I could see the debug output. And @chepner for the link how to debug a shell script. The issue was I had an alias defined in my .bashrc called tr and debug output revealed it. Once I replaced the line 'aws_env=$( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$1" )` with `typeset -u aws_env="$1"`, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mapfile` instead of `read` like so...

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check 1 argument is passed with the script
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage : $0 AWS account: e.g. $0 dev"
        exit 0
fi

# convert the input to uppercase
aws_env=$( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$1" )


if ! [[ "$aws_env" =~ ^(DEV|UAT|TRN|PROD)$ ]]; then 
    # check that correct account is provided
    echo "Enter correct AWS account: dev or uat or trn or prod"
    exit 0

else
    # export environment variables
    file="/home/xyz/.aws/key_${aws_env}"

    # IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < $file
    mapfile -t lines < "$file"

    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${lines[0]}
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${lines[1]}
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2
    echo "AWS access keys and secret has been exported as environment variables for $aws_env account"
fi
```

Make sure you also put quotation marks around `"$file"`

Another little tip, Bash supports making variables uppercase directly, like so:

```sh
var="upper"
echo "${var^^}"
```

Comment: Same result with mapfile, it closes the terminal.

Comment: Oh̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶,̶ ̶y̶e̶a̶h̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶`̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶i̶n̶g̶`̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶e̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶B̶a̶s̶h̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶u̶i̶l̶t̶i̶n̶ ̶`̶e̶x̶i̶t̶`̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶e̶x̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶B̶a̶s̶h̶ ̶s̶e̶s̶s̶i̶o̶n̶.̶ ̶S̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶e̶x̶i̶t̶`̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶`̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶`̶s̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e. Just saw your edit...